# Symfony2 form validation of respective fields

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

In symfony2.7 i have a form having four numeric fields. On submission how can I validate under following two situations separately:

1) total of these four values should not be more than 100. 
Or
2) total of last three field values should be equal to the value of first field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off situation in your application (if it isn't I'd write a [custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) for this), you can do a quick check in your controller after you handle the form and before the valid check.

For example;

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

class ArtistPhotoController extends Controller {

    // ...

    public function myFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create the form
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
                    ->add('number1', 'number', [
                            'required' => false,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->add('number2', 'number', [
                            'required' => false,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->add('number3', 'number', [
                            'required' => false,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->add('number4', 'number', [
                            'required' => false,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->add('submit', 'submit', ['label' => 'Check'])
                    ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // checky check for custom validation
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $number1 = $form->get('number1')->getData();
            $number2 = $form->get('number2')->getData();
            $number3 = $form->get('number3')->getData();
            $number4 = $form->get('number4')->getData();

            if (($number2+$number3+$number4) !== $number1) {
                $form->get('number1')->addError(new FormError('Num1 not equal to 2+3+4'));
            } 
            // any other rules you want to make up...
        }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // do whatever
        }

        return $this->render('MyBundle:foo:bar.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```